# Запуск приложения

Tags: windows, exe

Всем привет.

Имеется приложение, назовем его 1.exe (основное приложение), и имеется файл 2.exe (updator файлов), лежит на директорию выше. В общем, нужно сделать так, чтобы при запуске 1.exe запускался 2.exe и ничего кроме, а уже в окне 2.exe после проверки обновлений и целостности файлов запускался фаил 1.exe, т.е. основное приложение, но уже без проверки обновлений. Кто что может сказать?

Comment: При запуске 1.exe скрыть его форму и вызвать 2.exe, после отработки 2.exe показать форму 1.exe. 

Общение между двумя программами можете построить на любом принципе: будь-то создание файла, или заголовки окон, или буфер-обмена, или по handle передавать от одного окна другому сообщения, или иной любой путь взаимодействия.

Comment: Можно каким то примером показать? На чем вообще это писать?

Comment: @HolySaint, на любом языке программирования, по другому никак. Пример будет зависеть от выбранного языка.

Answer (score 1):

Открываешь блокнот, пишешь там две строки:

```
start /wait /min calc.exe
start mshearts.exe
```

Сохраняешь под любым именем с расширением cmd. Опционально создаешь ярлык, ставишь там галочки "Запускать в свернутом виде" и "Закрывать окно по завершении работы".

P.S. Вот и выросло поколение людей, которые даже не знают, что такое bat-файлы...

Comment: Спасибо. Я и забыл, что можно так просто сделать. )

Comment: Не помогло. Приложение запускается вместе с апдеитером. Можно ли как то в уже имеющийся фаил .exe внедрить запуск сначала апдеитера->обновление->запуск приложения (продолжение загрузки приложения)? .exe фаил зашифрован, но все подключеные .dll просматриваются через cff explorer. Мож но ли написать .dll для этого с проверкой на присутствие этого фаила. Ну что бы не получилось так, что удалили этот фаил или так же не удалили через cff explorer и программа запустилась без апдеитера?

Comment: Честно говоря, я мало что понял из объяснений, но если решать задачу в общем виде, то следующие две идеи у меня были бы такие:

1. Прописать апдейт в автозагрузку, чтобы он по-любому происходил раньше запуска основного приложения.
2. Написать скрипт на AutoHotKey, PowerShell или еще на чем-нибудь.

Трудно сказать точнее, не зная специфику приложений. Я не удивлюсь, если потом окажется, что у приложений есть ключи командной строки, которые делают то, что Вам надо. Бывают такие казусы, уверяю Вас...